# Why isn't my implementation of a Where function working?

Tags: javascript, filtering

I'm trying to implement a `Where` clause. My attempt

```
Object.prototype.Where = function ( boofunc ) {
  // Returns an object whose own properties are  
  // those properties p of this object that satisify
  // the condition boofunc(p)
  var that = {};
  for ( var prop in this )
  {
    var val = this[prop];
    if ( boofunc(val) )
    {
        that.prop = val;
    }
  }
  return that;
}

var obj = { x : 10, y : 11, z : 12 };
var evens = obj.Where(function(prop){obj.prop%2==0});
console.log(evens); // TEST
```

is not working (the object printed to the console doesn't have `x`, `y` or `z`). Or is there a better way of getting a filtered version of an existing object?

Comment: Note you are adding the `Where` method as an enumerable property. And then you use a `for...in`, which iterates all enumerable properties in the prototype chain. This may be undesirable. Consider adding the method as non-enumerable, or checking `hasOwnProperty` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Object.prototype.Where = function ( boofunc ) {
    // Returns an object whose own properties are  
  // those properties p of this object that satisify
  // the condition boofunc(p)
    var that = {};
    for ( var prop in this )
    {
        var val = this[prop];
        if ( boofunc(val) )
        {
        that[prop] = val;
        }
    }
    return that;
}

var obj = { x : 10, y : 11, z : 12 };
var evens = obj.Where(function(prop){ return prop % 2==0; });
console.log(evens); // TEST
```

Basically, you need to return the value from your `boofunc`, instead of just checking `prop % == 0` you have to actually return its result.

Next, you had a couple of typos, such as `obj.prop` where `obj` doesn't exist and also setting the property like `that[prop] = val;` instead of `that.prop = val;`

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t32jywje/1/

Comment: I thought `that[prop]` and `that.prop` were interchangable

Comment: @SubparWebDev `that['prop']` is interchangeable with `that.prop`, but `that[prop]` without quotes, will evaluate the subexpression `(prop)` to determine the property name, which is what you wanted since `prop` evaluates to the string property name that you actually want.

Comment: @SubparWebDev Objects in JavaScript are composed by **key : value** pairs, such as a **hastable / dictionary** in other programming languages. You can access a property by its name through ***dot notation***: `that.prop` and also you can access via the ***key*** as string in the hash: `that['prop']`. In the `for... in` loop, the variable `prop` carries the property name, thus `that[prop]` is accessing the property by its name via ***key*** in the hash.

Comment: In ES6, it can be simplified with arrow functions: `obj.Where(prop => prop%2==0)`